# double input with Scanner(System.in)

Tags: java

Хочу с помощью сканнера ввести значения типа `double`. При вводе `0.5` вылетает исключение из метода `nextDouble()`, а при `0,5` - всё ок.

Это нормальное поведение по умолчанию? Как изменить на ввод с точкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanner использует локаль для определения вводимых значений. Для определения точки вместо запятой, как разделителя десятичных чисел, необходимо изменить локаль например так

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

В комментариях к [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150679/2929220) ответу дан еще один вариант записи.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего дело в локали. Для некоторых используется запятая. Если вам нужно реагирование на точку, тогда можно написать так:

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
inp.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Должно сработать

p.s. Локали находятся в `java.util.Locale`